# How to join two RDDs by key to get RDD of (String, String)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two paired rdds in the form RDD [(String, mutable.HashSet[String]):

For example:

```
rdd1: 332101231222, "320758, 320762, 320760, 320759, 320757, 320761"
rdd2: 332101231222, "220758, 220762, 220760, 220759, 220757, 220761"
```

I want to combine rdd1 and rdd2 based on common keys, so o/p should be like:
332101231222 320758, 320762, 320760, 320759, 320757, 320761 220758, 220762, 220760, 220759, 220757, 220761

Here is my code:

```
def cogroupTest (rdd1: RDD [(String, mutable.HashSet[String])], rdd2: RDD [(String, mutable.HashSet[String])] ): Unit =
{

val prods_per_user_co_grouped = (rdd1).cogroup(rdd2)

prods_per_user_co_grouped.map { case (key: String, (value1: mutable.HashSet[String], value2:  mutable.HashSet[String])) => {
 val combinedhs = value1 ++ value2
 val sstr =  combinedhs.mkString("\t")
 val keypadded = key + "\t"
  s"$keypadded$sstr"
}
}.saveAsTextFile("/scratch/rdds_joined/")
```

Here is the error that I get when I run the my program:

> scala.MatchError: (32101231222,(CompactBuffer(Set(320758, 320762, 320760, 320759, 320757, 320761)),CompactBuffer(Set(220758, 220762, 220760, 220759, 220757, 220761)))) (of class scala.Tuple2)

Any help with this will be great!

Answer (score 2):

As you might guess from the name `cogroup` groups observations by key. It means that in your case you get:

```
(String, (Iterable[mutable.HashSet[String]], Iterable[mutable.HashSet[String]]))
```

not

```
(String, (mutable.HashSet[String], mutable.HashSet[String]))
```

It is pretty clear when you take a look at the error you get. If you want to combine pairs you should use `join` method. If not you should adjust pattern to match structure you get and then use something like this:

```
val combinedhs = value1.reduce(_ ++ _) ++ value2.reduce(_ ++ _)
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to get the following op:

rdd1: key1, "str1"
rdd2: key1, "str2"

results: key1, "str1 str2"
I am not sure if join will work when I want to combine them by key in the above fashion.

Comment: Join is similar to SQL inner join and `rdd1.cogroup(rdd2)` is more or less equivalent to `rdd1.groupByKey.join(rdd2.groupByKey.)`