# Joining multiple pairedrdds

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a question regarding joining multiple rdds simultaneously. I have about 8 paired rdds of datatype: RDD [(String, mutable.HashSet[String])]. I would like to join them by key. I can join 2 using spark's join or cogroup?
However, is there a build-in way to do this? I can join two-at a time and then join the result rdd with the next one, however if there is any better way, would like to use that.

Comment: Could either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work for you? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method to join multiple RDDs. Assuming this question is related to [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32302417/1560062) and you want to combine sets for each key you can simply use `union` followed by `reduceByKey`:

```
val rdds = Seq(rdd1, rdd2, ..., rdd8)
val combined: RDD[(String, mutable.HashSet[String])] = sc
  .union(rdds)
  .reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

If not you can try to reduce a collection of RDDs:

```
val combined: RDD[(String, Seq[mutable.HashSet[String]])] = rdds
  .map(_.mapValues(s => Seq(s)))
  .reduce((a, b) => a.join(b).mapValues{case (s1, s2) => s1 ++ s2})
```

Comment: These 2 are pretty  much the best ways you can do joins over multiple RDDs in Spark. Great answer.